# Check for uniqueness on mongodb database before submitting react hook form

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hook-form, zod

I would like to implement a way to check if the value of a react hook form input is unique on my database before allowing the user submitting the form.

Currently im using zod for validating the form to create a new recipe like this:

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  recipeId: z.string(),
  name: z
    .string()
    .min(4, { message: "Name must be 4 or more characters long" }),
  description: z.string(),
});
```

Im already using a schema middleware on my backend to ensure that the recipeId is unique before saving the document to my mongodb database. But its a very bad user experience if the request fails because the recipeId is already in use.

Now i would like to check if the recipeId is unique on my database before allowing the user to submit the form. In the best case the information if the recipeId is not unique appears as a zod message.

What would you consider as a best practice to do this?

Comment: Have you checked out [unique indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/)?

Comment: @ray Ah thank you. So i dont have to use a custom middleware for the backend database part.

Comment: @lexer, your chosen way is best among other methods, validate needed partial data in the backend instead of all of them using submitting, to do that you can create a route in your backend to validate that **id** and nothing else, then plug it with your _zod schema_, there is a way to do custom validation using [refine](https://zod.dev/?id=refine), it handles async functions too, that you can do the backend call in it.

Comment: @HediM.Aziz Thank you. Just saw it in the docs.